# Chrome 56 mobile addEventListener "click" not working

Tags: google-chrome, events, mobile, click, touch

I encounter a problem where `click` event on Link Element (A tag), or any other DOM Element, is not calling handler/callback function.

it doesn't matter which parent in the hierarchy I am getting it not getting this event.

no Event.stopImmediatePropagation or Event.stopPropagation exist.

Answer (score 5):

the reason why is Chrome 56, they change some of the events and stop transforming Mouse Events to Touch Events.

see here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/chrome-56-deprecations#mouse_on_android_stops_firing_touchevents

to solve the issue just use `touchstart` event for mobile where you used `click` before. or if you need only one `click` you can do:

```
Element.addEventListener("click", callback);
Element.addEventListener("touchstart", callback);
function callback(event) {
  Element.removeEventListener("click", callback);
  Element.removeEventListener("touchstart", callback);
  // do something
}
```

now, to have a simulate click you need to check 300ms pass between "touchstart" and "touchend". if it less you have a click.

Note: the "click" event occur after "touchstart"

Comment: Nice catch, recommend implementing by yourself or using https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/lib/fastclick.js